# How to configure octobercms plugin settings?

Tags: octobercms

I just want to add the configuration for a plugin made in octobercms. just need a database field in backend to add api key

Comment: please check this : https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/settings ( API key example also given ), if you face any issues please tell us we will help you.

Comment: https://octobercms.com/forum/post/get-email-settings-in-my-plugin, i m using this tutorial but getting the issue described in the last comment

Comment: solved there was a mistake in namespace, thanks